# railstutorial (rails 4) editing post gives Routing Error "/posts.5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning rails 4 with this tutorial:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Till now I could fix every thing but now there is a problem after I edit a post and then I would like to save it, but it sends me to `localhost:3000/posts.7` (7 is the post id)

When i go over /posts/new and then click the submit button, it works

This is the Error I get.

```
    Routing Error
    No route matches [PATCH] "/posts.7"

    Rails.root: /home/spod/railstutorial/blog
    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

    Routes

    Routes match in priority from top to bottom
    Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
    Path / Url 

    posts_path  GET     /posts(.:format)    posts#index
                POST    /posts(.:format)    posts#create
    new_post_path   GET     /posts/new(.:format)    posts#new
    edit_post_path  GET     /posts/:id/edit(.:format)   posts#edit
    post_path   GET     /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#show
                PATCH   /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
                PUT     /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
                DELETE  /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#destroy
    root_path   GET     /   welcome#index
```

here the `posts_controller.rb`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def terra
 end

 def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end

 def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
   rederict_to @post
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def index
  @posts = Post.all
 end

 def create
   @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

   if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
   else
    render 'new'

   end
  end

  private
   def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

 end
```

Here is the `edit.html.erb`

```
<h1>Editing post</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path(@post), method: :patch do |f| %>
 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
   <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.label :text %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.submit %>
 </p>
<% end %>

<% link_to 'Home', posts_path %>
```

and here is the `new.html.erb`

```
 <h1>New Post</h1>

 <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being      saved:</h2>
   <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
   <%= f.label :title %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
   <%= f.label :text %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
  </p>
 <% end %>


 <%=link_to 'Home', posts_path %>
```

I hope this is everything you need
Thanks for helbing

Answer (score 0):

you `edit.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for :post, url: edit_post_path(@post), method: :patch do |f| %>
 <% if @post.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
   <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

you need to specify the correct path that points to the right action

Comment: Well, closer.  The url should be post_path(@post).  They're already on the edit_post_path.

Comment: You can not specify the link `form_for @post, method: :patch do`

Comment: Yes, you can specify the url if you like.  As with everything in Rails, there are conventions and options to override those conventions.  For example, I have a large application that relies heavily on namespaces in both the model and controller layers.  The model and controller namespaces do not always align so the inferred url for an object would be wrong if I relied simply on Rails to calculate the path based on the instance variable.

Comment: I agree with you. But there will be enough of it.

Comment: I think that perhaps we're disagreeing over semantics.  "You can not specify the link" suggests that it is not possible to specify the link.  I am disagreeing with that.  I think that perhaps you meant, "You can omit the link" which hints at the fact that it is possible to override the link but not necessary.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, try this

```
<%= form_for @post, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
```

instead of this

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path(@post), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

Hope it works in your end.